# How to install Fontin in Mac

Tags: macos, font, latex

Could anyone please let me know how to install fontin which I download from [Exljbris](http://www.exljbris.com/fontin.html). I am new to mac so I am not sure what to do with .sit file.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to get the file out of the .sit.

Head over to the Mac App Store and download either The Unarchiver or Stuffit Expander.

When you launch The Unarchiver, you’ll be asked where to extract stuff.

```
Would you like The Unarchiver to extract archives to the same folder as the archive file, or would you prefer to be asked for a destination folder for every individual archive?
```

Go ahead and choose Extract to the Same Folder, unless you have nothing better to do than answer your Mac’s constant questioning. You can then mess about with settings, or just click on the File menu and Unarchive your file. You can also drag a .sit file right to The Unarchiver’s Dock icon, or right click on a .sit file and choose Open With, then The Unarchiver.

The same goes for Stuffit expander – download it, let it install, and then use it to unarchive your .sit files. Easy!

[Read more at](http://www.cultofmac.com/192682/open-sit-files-in-mountain-lion-for-free-os-x-tips/#MJMt4w5WwGkqDI26.99)

---

Open Font Book in your Applications folder.

Under File tab select Add Fonts,.

Find your file in the search window.